# Trying to put SHOW DATABASES to a combobox in C# gives me list of System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, mysql, database, combobox, show

I was trying to put a list of databases from mySQL server, to a combobox in C#. when i click on a button to fill it, it gives me list of "System.Data.DataRowView"
instead of values.

Can u tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Here is source code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=servname;uid=" + this.login.Text + ";pwd=" + password.Text + ";");
                MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SHOW DATABASES;", conn);

            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            mda.Fill(ds, "box");
            this.dataBase.DataSource = ds.Tables["box"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Combobox's .DisplayMember property to a field of the DataRowView. The DataRowView is the entire row object, the DisplayMember allows you to specify what, in that object to display.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer !

Can u explain it to me ? I'm just a begginer and since the show databases query returns just one collumn i don't know how to set DisplayMember properly ... to witch collumn should I bond it.

Comment: Sure, first, what is the column name being returned.

Comment: It's named Database, just saw it in MySQL Front ... I'm just not sure in which place should i bond it to combobox (named database).

Comment: then you should be able to add `this.dataBase.DisplayMember = "Database";` and see the actual values from the datarow in the combobox.